# Resolving 10060, 'Operation timed out'

Tags: python, sockets, timeout

Does anyone know how to prevent this error from occurring: IOError:

```
[Errno socket error] (10060, 'Operation timed out').
```

I am using the following code without any luck. Obviously I am missing
something.

```
import socket
socket.setdefaulttimeout(20)
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some more detail, such as the code that you're running when the exception is raised, and how long it takes to raise it.

Answer (score 0):

Using none as the argument to setdefaulttimeout will cause new socket objects to have no timeout.

```
socket.setdefaulttimeout(20)
```

Or, you can turn off timeouts for individual sockets:

```
sock = socket.socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) # For example
sock.settimeout(None)
```

Source: http://docs.python.org/library/socket.html